# Find the topology $\tau$ on $X$ whose subbase is $S$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $X=${$a,b,c,d,e$}
Let $S=${{$a,b,d$},{$b,d,e$}}
Find the topology $\tau$ on $X$ whose subbase is $S$.

**Definitions:**

A subbase for the topology X is the collection $S$ of open subsets of X such that the collection of all intersections of finite subcollections of S is a base for $X$.

A base for the topology $\tau$ is a subcollection of $\mathbb B\subset \tau$ such that every element of $\tau$ is the union of some subcollection of $\mathbb B$

**Thoughts:**

So I'm looking for some topology $\tau$ such that if I take the union of all of the elements of $\tau$ then I'll receive the group $S$.

I'm having trouble making this $\tau$ though becuase of the $a$ and $e$. I can get my topology to have {

So my topology $\tau$ could include {$b,d$}, but the miunte I try to in the {a} or {e} I get the union of the {a} or {e} I included to contain things that aren't in $S$. Just not sure if I'm under or over thinking this problem. Thanks.

Comment: When you have a subbase you only need to add the whole space and after simply make all the finite intersections and countable unions.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't look for some topology $\tau$ such that the union of all elements of $\tau$ will give you $S$. If $\tau$ is a topology, then the collection of the union of all its elements will be $\tau$.  $\tau$ must contain all unions of finite intersections of elements of $S$, hence $$\tau = \{ \emptyset, X, \{a,b,d\}, \{b,d,e\}, \{b,d\}\, \{ a,b,d,e\}\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I find it little bit hard to interpret where you are in trouble, let me just give a standard textbook-like solution.

Step 1. Find the basis $\mathbb{B}$ obtained from $S$.
As there are only two elements $\alpha=\left\{a,b,d\right\},\beta=\left\{b,d,e\right\}$, $\mathbb{B}=\left\{X, \alpha,\beta, \alpha\cap \beta=\left\{b,d\right\}\right\}$(Note the nullary intersection convention here gives you $X$).

Step 2. Generating the topology $\tau$ from the basis $\mathbb{B}$.
$\tau$ is the set of all possible subsets of $X$ obtained by arbitrarily many unions of elements of $\mathbb{B}$. As there are only 3 nontrivial elements in $\mathbb{B}$ and $\left\{b,d\right\}$ is the minimum of $\alpha,\beta$, we know that only $\alpha\cup \beta=\left\{a,b,d,e\right\}$ should be added. So the final answer is $\tau=\left\{\emptyset, X, \alpha,\beta, \left\{b,d\right\},\left\{a,b,d,e\right\}\right\}$, whose cardinality is 6.(Also note that the nullary union convention gives you $\emptyset$ here)

And please note that as $b$ and $d$ cannot be splitted in $S$, the topology $\tau$ also must not separate $b$ and $d$. Moreover, as $c$ is not contained in $S$, $c$ must be a generic point of $\tau$, that is, any open set including $c$ should be the entire set $X$.